# Is the Android 2.0 emulator Bluetooth enabled?

Tags: android

I want to know whether Android 2.0 emulator is Bluetooth enabled.If it is not enabled, then how can i test my bluetooth application.Please any body knows the solution help me.

Comment: If the host device has bluetooth then I guess its feasible it could utilise it, but if your machine does not have bluetooth, then how could it work?

Comment: Thanks for your comment ck .I case i am having bluetooth attached to my machine.How can i connect my Android emulator to that bluetooth device to test my application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Nope](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#limitations), you'll have to buy a real device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If i am having one real bluetooth device attached to my system. then how can connect my emulator with the bluetooth device.

Comment: @Rajapandian - "real device" meaning a real phone, not the emulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384461/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator  check this link, its possible using VM

Answer (score 3):

You can install the image from http://www.android-x86.org/ into a virtual machine (e.g. VMWare), find out it's IP address, connect manually using

```
adb connect <IP of VM>
```

And then launch your project from Eclipse by setting a "Manual" deployment target in your Debug/Run configuration. Bluetooth works in this Virtual Machine at least on my Macbook and it's reported to work with a couple of other bluetooth chipsets.

Comment: this works :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384461/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator

Answer (score 1):

there is an emulator written by 3rd party: https://github.com/cheng81/Android-Bluetooth-Simulator

but beware! there are bugs

Comment: Nice, but what I am looking for is something that actually uses the bluetooth on the laptop inside the emulator, not a bluetooth to tcp translator.

Answer (score 0):

Currently no, check here for updated status:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#limitations

Excerpt:
In this release, the limitations of the emulator include:

- No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator console, however.
- No support for USB connections
- No support for camera/video capture (input).
- No support for device-attached headphones
- No support for determining connected state
- No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging
  state
- No support for determining SD card insert/eject
- No support for Bluetooth

Comment: Yeah it takes a fake picture. Doesn't allow you to use something such as a web cam on your computer. Also as far as I am aware you can't change the picture it uses.