# Bluetooth support on Android Emulator

Tags: bluetooth, android-emulator

I want to know if the developer team which made the emulator have some information to make bluetooth work in the Android emulator, indicate some links about it, if they have some date for release or if they'll make it works in the future.

Answer (score 25):

as far as I know there is no support in the emulator for bluetooth. And I will have to teach android and bluetooth in some classes. And the students will need to code stuff and test (guess it) in the android emulator.

So I came up with a bare-bone reimplementation of the android bluetooth API on top of tcp. You can find it on [here on github](http://github.com/cheng81/Android-Bluetooth-Simulator).

Basically, you run a tcp-server on your machine, and the emulators will connect through it.
Instead of using the classes in the package `android.bluetooth`, you just need to use the classes in the package `dk.itu.android.bluetooth` (and other 2 little modifies).

As for now it supports:

- switch on/off the "radio"
- discovery devices (only other android emulators)
- creating bluetooth services
- connecting to bluetooth services

It's not much, but until we got some more from the android guys, I guess there is nothing else around.

Hope it'll be useful, cheers!

Comment: can we pass data using that library..?

Answer (score 0):

The documented bluetooth limitation appears inconsistent with the qemu `-bt` option.  So, how is bluetooth enabled in the emulator so the `-bt` options can be used, or at least to know that bluetooth is supported?

The target/board/.../BoardConfig.mk having "BOARD_HAVE_BLUETOOTH := true" doesn't provide a bluetooth icon or enable bluetooth. So, how do we turn on bluetooth on the android qemu emulator?

What does it mean that bluetooth is not supported given the `-bt` option for emulating USB devices that were provided in 2008?  The post and limitations are outdated.

The functional limitations of the emulator include:

No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator console, however.
No support for USB connections
No support for device-attached headphones
No support for determining network connected state
No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging state
No support for determining SD card insert/eject
No support for Bluetooth

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#limitations