# Why does eclipse give me errors when i try to run sample application?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, sample

I dont know why the sample application from the android website gives me 300+ errors when i try to run it in ecplise galileo. The application i am trying is Bluetoothchat it is straight from the sdk sample folder so it shouldn't contain any. I have added android.jar and I do have an emulator. I have tried HelloWorld and it worked..Could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Post the first few errors here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the emulator doesn't support Bluetooth (See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384461/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator)). Still the application should run and report that Bluetooth isn't available. Which API are you using? Also, do you get compile or runtime errors?