# Bluetooth on Google Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bluetooth support on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384461/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator)

Is it possible to use Bluetooth in emulation mode on google android? What is the current implementation of Bluetooth? Is it 2.1 +EDR?

Answer (score 0):

[The emulator does not emulate Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#limitations) -- sorry!