# unable to access Bluetooth in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth, android-2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bluetooth support on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384461/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator)

I want to run Bluetooth chat apps, but my emulator is unable to switch Bluetooth on. I am using Android 2.2. The Bluetooth option is not being highlighted in the emulator. how can I activate Bluetooth on the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Android Emulator does not support  for Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulator doesnt support Bluetooth. you have to have the real hardware for it.