# android 3.1: getDefaultAdapter() returns null in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

> mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
>           if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
>               Log.i("Error", "Bluetooth isn't supported");
>               return;
>           }

when I run this code on the emulator it prints "Bluetooth isn't supported".
any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The emulator does not support Bluetooth. However, someone created a workaround, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384461/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator), maybe it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator does not support Bluetooth facility.try in real device.