# Bluetooth support in Emulator in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bluetooth support on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384461/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator)

I want to develop an **Android Application** which works on **Bluetooth**.

But **Android Emulator** not supported **Bluetooth** So can't check application in Emulator.

Is **Android Emulator** supports **Bluetooth** ?

How I can achieve it ?

Thanks

Comment: it should be tagged with android....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Bluetooth development you'll have to use an actual device.  In fact, it's best to have 2 devices as you'll no doubtedly want to connect and transmit/receive data, and to test that requires a couple of handsets.

Comment: There is some way to achieve this. for example, using Virtual Machine we can achieve this . check this site and you can get a idea. http://niro-offonatangent.blogspot.com/2011/06/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator.html

Answer (score 2):

No, Android emulator does not support for bluetooth..