# Send data through bluetooth programmatically

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need to send data from my android phone to the android emulator that is in my PC through Bluetooth functionality. I understand there's a need of using the client and server side function. However, I don't understand how to invoke my methods into the onCreate function through these codes:

```
    public BluetoothSocketActivity(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        remoteDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666"));
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void runConnect() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        _bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothDeviceTest.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer) 
                .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    private void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket mmSocket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The android emulator does not support bluetooth.  You can see [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384461/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator) post for an optional library to install to emulate bluetooth over a TCP connection.