# Android Bluetooth is not supported

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am learning to use Bluetooth in Android. I have given this permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

and the main code lies here:

```
   private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TextView out=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.out);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
       out.append("device not supported");
    }
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }
    });
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                   Context context = getApplicationContext();
                   CharSequence text = "MAKING YOUR DEVICE DISCOVERABLE";
                   int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                   toast.show();
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT);
            }
        }               
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {    
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
               CharSequence text = "TURNING_OFF BLUETOOTH";
               int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
               toast.show();
            }
    });
}
```

But it is telling me:

> device not supported

on the screen and by clicking on a button makes the app force close so what is the problem with my android emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

emulator don't support bluetooth, use real device

Comment: I am  testing a sample code on emulator and I do not have android phone so is there any way to fix it??

Comment: have you made any project on emulator?

Comment: some application can test and development on the emulator, but some ca n not.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#limitations) about some limitations of Emulator before using Bluetooth in your application.

Answer (score 1):

`device not supported` is the message you get when

```
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
       out.append("device not supported");
    }
```

That is because the Android emulator does not support Bluetooh. You need a physical device to check Bluetooth enabled applications.

Check these questions for additional info

[How to use Bluetooth in Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175076/how-to-use-bluetooth-in-android-emulator)
[Bluetooth support on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384461/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

If bluetooth is not supported, then why have a qemu -bt option for the emulator and why is there an emulation for a usb keyboard over bluetooth? Need to enable bluetooth so it appears as supported. There is likely a particular configuration required or a particular target needed beyond adding BOARD_HAVE_BLUETOOTH := true to BoardConfig.mk?

How does one configure bluetooth so it is enabled in the emulator?

bt[:hci-type]
Bluetooth dongle whose type is specified in the same format as with the ‘-bt hci’ option, see allowed HCI types. If no type is given, the HCI logic corresponds to -bt hci,vlan=0. This USB device implements the USB Transport Layer of HCI. Example usage:

qemu [...OPTIONS...] -usbdevice bt:hci,vlan=3 -bt device:keyboard,vlan=3

http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#usb_005fdevices